Write to Firebase Realtime database: permission denied
I have a very simple website with a Firebase Realtime backend. I want everyone to be able to see the database, and only authenticated users to be able to write. My security rules are:
  { "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth !== null"
    }
  }

Should be fine, right? But I'm getting "permission denied" in the console. The exact error:


I verified that the user is really authenticated (var user = firebase.auth().currentUser).
I verified that writing to the database works when the write rule is set to "true".
I verified that writing works using the Firebase rules playground.

My JavaScript code that triggers the writing is (shortened):
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const database = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
  const rootRef = ref(database);

  function handleSubmit(event) {

     push(child(rootRef, '/'), {
        key: value
  }}

I've read countless threads here about "permission denied", but still couldn't find an answer appropriate to my situation. Please help.

Just to make sure, in the part where you checked that the user is really authenticated, did you also check that your user has an uid?

@Alex Yes, and the uid in the console matches the one in the Realtime database.

Okay, what version of firebase are you using? And do you also use App Check in firebase?

Firebase 10.10.0, and I don't know what App Check is.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

I wasn't able to replicate this issue. As what Alex and Puf said, did you, by any chance, register your app in App Check?

No, it's disabled.
